# Horsepower power ratings expalined

Tags: motor

Basic question guys,

I'm looking at replacing a pump motor, and the existing motor is rated for 1.25. My question is simple, is a 1.25 hp rating equivalent to 1/25HP?

Comment: 1/25 is 0.04. So, no, it's not the same as 1.25.

Comment: If it's any help in comparing with other motor ratings, 1 HP = 750 W (watts) approximately.

Answer (score 3):

If the rating plate is clearly marked 1.25 it means what it says, one and one quarter horsepower. That is not a standard motor that you can easily buy, but it may be available as a replacement part or you can replace it with a 1.5 Hp motor. If you think that the marking is wrong, look at the physical size of the motor. A 1/25 Hp motor will fit in the palm of your hand and will have a shaft that is in the neighborhood of 1/8 inch in diameter.